# Concatenate string in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

EDIT: This string is a part of json and i am writing it onto a file. In that json file i see the escape charaters. With console.log, I don't see any escape character.

I am trying to concatenate a string such that I get the following output:

```
"OR("1admin", "2admin")"
```

But the output I keep on getting is

```
"OR(\"1admin\", \"2admin\")"
```

Sample code

```js
var str = "OR("
for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  str += '"' + i + 'admin' + '", ';
}
str = str.trim().substring(0, str.length - 2).concat(')')
console.log(str)
```

I have tried using regex and string split.
eg.

`.replace(/'/g, '"')` This when i tried something like this `"'" + i + "admin" + "', "` and tried to replace `'` with `"`

```
.split('\\').join('').trim() This also didn' work.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `"OR("1admin", "2admin")"` is not a syntactically correct string. The second one on the other hand is a string with the character sequence you want: i.e. `'O', 'R', '(', '"', ... `. In other words, you already got the right result. The string `"\""` is the string consisting of the character `'"'`. A backlash character '\' is required to escape the '"' character so that it doesn't break string parsing early.

Comment: @fk82 that would be a good answer :)

Comment: See [escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation) and [Single quotes vs. double quotes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings#Single_quotes_vs._double_quotes) | your output is actually correct...

Comment: @JonasWilms Technically I'm not answering the question. Let's see what OP says. :)

Comment: @adiga it was missing one `'` at end in original code

Comment: @CodeManiac since OP got the output, I assumed that was as typo when posting here. I'll revert it to to the previous version if it's relevant to the question. OP doesn't seem to mention any syntax error.

Comment: @fk82 for sure you do. And 4 people agree to it.

Comment: @adiga yeah that's fine, but that completely changes the question

Comment: @CodeManiac OP thinks there is a literal backslash in the string when there isn't. So, I assumed the syntax error was not the problem here.

Comment: Ok so i didn't explain properly. I am writing json on to a file and in json I see the escape characters. console.log doesn't show any escape charater.

Comment: Without the \ it would be invalid JSON then.

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban is the last character inside the for loop a single quote or a double quote? You posted it with a double quote which is a syntax error

Comment: @adiga I tried with single quote and double quote both. Got the same output.

Comment: @prisoner_of_azkaban No, I meant the code you have posted here. It is throwing a syntax error because the last character should be a double quote and not a single quote..

Comment: oh let me edit the question. @adiga

Comment: HOW are you writing the JSON to the file? My guess is you are doing something else or it is 100% correct that it is being escaped so the JSON is valid

Comment: `fse.outputFileSync(outputfilePath, JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));`
where fse is fs-extra

Comment: And what is result? Code above shows you building a string.... So you would be JSON encoding a string, not an object. ANd as everyone says `{ "foo" : "I say \"Hello\" world" }` is valid JSON

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you already got the correct result in your original snippet.

If the character escape syntax seems curious to you, I'd recommend something like the following using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

You can write the `"` in template strings unescaped and use interpolation to print your variables.

**Edit**: Seems like you want JSON formatting. You can use `JSON.stringify` for that. JSON formatted strings will contain escape characters that show up in `console.log` output.

```js
const f = (n, s) => {
    const a = new Array(n)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => `"${i + 1}${s}"`);
    return `OR(${a.join(', ')})`;
}

console.log(`output: ${f(2, "admin")}`)
console.log(`json-formatted: ${JSON.stringify(f(2, "admin"))}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job:

```
const NUM_ADMINS = 2;
const CONCAT_STRING =
 `OR(${
   Array(NUM_ADMINS)
   .fill()
   .map((_, idx) => `"${idx + 1}admin"`)
   .join(", ")})`;
```

It creates a new array with the needed number of admins, then maps it to strings in th form "admin", joins with a comma and a space. And then it it is all wrapped in a "OR()" string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '"OR("'
var adm = 'admin"'
var end = ')"'
for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
  str += i + adm + ', '
}
str = str.trim().substring(0, str.length - 2)
str += end
console.log(str);
```

try running this snippet. if the implementation is fyn for you. Result is what you expected.